# (Javascript) .click() an clickable div inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Imagine the situation, where I have an iframe of a website.
Inside that website there is a button in which I want to click via javascript.

After looking into the HTML of the website, I noticed that the button is actually a div, with class `like`.

So I tried this:

```
function likeFunction() 
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("div")[10];
    elmnt.click();
}
```

or

```
function likeFunction() 
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("div")[10].click();
}
```

and my final attempt was giving that div an ID='ex'

```
function likeFunction() 
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("ex").click();
}
```

But in the end, nothing really did it for me, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the domain of the iframe the same as the domain your JS is running on? If not, you won't be able to trigger a click in the iframe due to browser security reasons.

Comment: Did you get any errors? Other than that, your approach should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution should work, as long as the iFrame is on the same domain. If it is not, you should get an error on this line

> ```
> iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("div")[10].click();
> ```

So you would probably have noticed.

My only thoughts are:

- you might be using the wrong selector,
- you might be running the posted script on the iframe itself, not on the parent scope
- you might be running this before the iFrame is loaded. Maybe running this onDocumentComplete on the parent document or some other way.
- The click listener might be on on different element than the one you are progamatically clicking on.

But in the scenarios I mentioned, you should be getting an error, which you didn't mention.

Otherwise, the general approach works on my tests.